# Auto Calculating for input field values

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Html is like this:

```
<input class="gbTransform" type="text" name="maxdl" value=""/>
```

And javascript like this:

```
$('.gbTransform').change(function(){
        var sz = $(this).val().match(/(\d+)gb/i);
        if(sz.length > 1){
          $(this).val(parseInt(sz[1])*1024);
        }
    });
```

What this does is when a user types 1gb it will automatically calculate into mbs (1 * 1024 = 1024) and change the input fields value.

This works fine but when user types `1.5gb` its calculates `5 * 1024` which is incorrect it should be `1.5 * 1024`

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear all "gb" strings and use `parseFloat`:

```
parseFloat("1.5"); // 1.5
```

Example:

```
var a = "1.5gb".replace("gb", "");
document.print(parseFloat(a));
```

Comment: Still I am getting an incorrect answer I change parseInt to parseFloat but when I type `1.5gb` the value of field is calculated as `5 * 1024 = 5120` instead of `1.5 * 1024 = 1536`